# Syncfusion date-picker doesn't work properly with angular reactive forms

Tags: datepicker, angular-reactive-forms, angular7, syncfusion

In my Angular 7.0 project, I use two Syncfusion date-pickers to show 'created by' date and the 'modified by' date. 
The controls work fine with the exact same data when I use tempalte driven approach with "[(ngModel)]".

The same controls on the same page doesn't work when I use it inside a reactive form. It just give me an error on the console (value.match is not a function) and show me just two textboxes instead the usual date controls. As you can see in the HTML file, I converted the school object to JSON and see the value for the date figures same time. I did not see any incompatibility there too.

.HTML File

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="pt-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-10">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <span>Created date</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <!-- This is doesn't work -->
                  <ejs-datepicker #createdDate class="syncfusion-dtp" placeholder='Enter date' format="dd-MM-yyyyy" aria-label="Created date"
                                  [readonly]="true" [disabled]="true"
                                  formControlName="createdOn" name="Created On"></ejs-datepicker>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="float-right ml-1 btn btn-info " [disabled]="!registerForm.valid">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <!-- This works -->
      <ejs-datepicker class="syncfusion-dtp" placeholder='Enter date' format="dd-MM-yyyyy" aria-label="Modified date"
                      [readonly]="true" [disabled]="true"
                      [(ngModel)]="school.modifiedOn" name="Modified On"></ejs-datepicker>
```

.ts file

```
export class ListItemViewEditComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Output() notifyParentOnUpdate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() schoolObject: School;
  school = new School();
  schoolNumber: number;
  @ViewChild('createdDate') createdDate: DatePicker;
  @ViewChild('modifiedDate') modifiedDate: DatePicker;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute, private schoolsService: SchoolsService) { }

  registerForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    schoolNumber: ['', Validators.required],
    schoolName: [''],
    description: [''],
    createdOn: [''],
    createdBy: [''],
    modifiedOn: [''],
    modifiedBy: ['']
  });


  ngOnChanges() {
    this.school = this.schoolObject;
    this.registerForm.setValue({
      id: [this.school.id],
      schoolNumber: [this.school.schoolNumber],
      schoolName: [this.school.schoolName],
      description: [this.school.description],
      createdOn: [this.school.createdOn],
      createdBy: [this.school.createdBy],
      modifiedOn: [this.school.modifiedOn],
      modifiedBy: [this.school.modifiedBy]
    });
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check,

- In the app.module.ts make sure you have imported `ReactiveFormsModule`.
- In the component class, `registerForm` has been declared and set the type to `FormGroup` (Not essential, but let's follow good practices)
- Move the `registerForm` declaration inside `ngOnInit` (Very first line)

I have created a StackBlitz example for you - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-synfunction-datepicker

In the example I have set the `[disabled]=false` and `[readonly]=false`. So, I can see the actual date picker popup.

If you are struggling to set the value of the datepicker. Make a function and set the value inside the function and call it from somewhere. (i.e. NgOnInit, NgOnChange)

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the likely cause of this issue must be related to string parsing. The error “value.match is not a function” must be because, the type of value is not  a string, since match is a method that belongs to String prototype. So, ensure if there is a type mismatching error in your application.

For your reference, I have prepared a sample with Syncfusion Datepicker using Angular Reactive forms.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eix8bh-z25gns?file=reactiveform.component.ts

If this does not help, you can contact the Syncfusion support center in the below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents